# How to make up elements which covers the individual cells(which has its own content) of a table in html?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a table with some of its cells covered by a grey intransparent block (which only covers the cell without extending itself beyong the cell). The contents in the cells should also be covered.

This is the relevant [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zva0s8bL/21/).

However, I can not make it such that the content is covered. I have been trying around with "position" of the div element responsible for the blocks in CSS, but the effect is either not covering the cell content or the block extends itself beyond the cell.

The javascript code:

```
var x = document.createElement("table");
x.setAttribute("id", "table");
document.body.appendChild(x);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
    var y = document.createElement("tr");
    y.setAttribute("id", 'tr' + i);
    document.getElementById("table").appendChild(y);
    var j;
    var temp;
    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) { 
        var z = document.createElement("th");
        z.setAttribute("id", 'th' + i +j);
        var t;
        var temp;
        if(i == 0){
          t = document.createTextNode(-(12-1-j));
        }else{
          t = document.createTextNode('abc');

          temp = document.createElement('div');
          temp.setAttribute('class', 'first');
          console.log(temp)
          temp.setAttribute('id', 'shadow'+ j);
          z.appendChild(temp);
        }
        z.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById('tr' + i).appendChild(z);        

    }

}
```

Comment: I think I have achieved what you want . Please refer to this fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/7Ldx0pm8/1/)

Comment: @ShubhamYerawar You can make it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a separate class to text and then use `position:relative` to position your component with respect to grey area.

For working example please refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Ldx0pm8/1/)